# Fail to fetch POST info

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm learning backend node/express. In this block of code I'm trying to send some data to backend but i get Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch. Thank you.

Backend:

```
    const path = require("path")
const express =require("express")
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()

const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, "..","client", 'dist')
const publicPath2 = path.join(__dirname, "..","client", 'public')
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000


app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.static(publicPath))
app.use(express.static(publicPath2))

app.use(express.urlencoded)


app.get("*", (req,res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(publicPath, 'index.html'))
})

//edit

app.post('/api', (req, res) => {
console.log('I got a req')
console.log(req.body)
const data = req.body
res.json({
    status:'success',
    cart:data.cart
})
```

})

```
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('server is up')
})
```

frontEnd

```
const submitAuthor = async () => {
        const result = await fetch('/api', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(cart)
        })
        const data= await result.json()
        console.log(data)
      }
```

Edited the response part.

Comment: `app.post('/api', (req, res) => { console.log('I got a req'); })` — you forgot to send a response.

Comment: Thank you.. it is still not working tho after I added a response. When i go to network in the browser it just says "pending" on the api promise.

Comment: @raduc: Can you edit the question with the updated code?

Comment: Did you remember to re-run the server code after changing it? The new code won't take effect in the already running program in memory.

Comment: @David Thank you for you answer, i edited now. Quentin yes.. i'm also using nodemon. But maybe what i edited is wrong. Also the status of the fetch is still pending.

Comment: @raduc: `response.json({...` - What is `response`?  The "response" object in that operation is called `res`.  Surely this is producing an error server-side.

Comment: yes.. indeed. You are right. still doesnt work.

Comment: Remove the line `app.use(express.urlencoded)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser knows how to send only `GET` requests, unless you specify somehow that you need another method (like using a form). So if you just try to access that endpoint through the url, a GET request will be sent by the browser, not a POST one

Comment: "Your browser knows how to send only GET requests" — That's incorrect

Comment: "unless you specify somehow that you need another method" — The did that on line 3 of the  frontend JS they posted in the question.

Comment: If the problem *was* that they were making a GET request by mistake then they would hit the `app.get("*",` and get an HTML document in response.